# Unity3D www.error returning "cannot connect to destination host" and crash on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash

I encountered crashes on IOS during a WWW post request with WWWForm. This works fine on Android and the UnityEditor itself, but it keeps crashing on iOS whenever the www line is executed.

Is there anything I missed which caused the crash on iOS? Or is there any specific reason that caused this problem? (I am quite new to this area so any advice, solutions or suggestions would be much appreciated.)

I was trying to add a new card to trello with this code snippet. (The key and token was gotten from Trello itself.) This was the the code that does the request:

```
private const string cardBaseUrl = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/";
 
public IEnumerator UploadCardCO(Card card)
        {
            WWWForm post = new WWWForm();
            post.AddField("name", card.name);
            post.AddField("desc", card.desc);
            post.AddField("pos", card.pos);
            post.AddField("due", card.due);
            post.AddField("idList", card.idList);
 
            WWW www = new WWW(cardBaseUrl + "?" + "key=" + key + "&token=" + token, post);
            yield return www;
        }
 
public IEnumerator SendReportCO( Card card )
{
        yield return this.StartCoroutine( trello.UploadCardRoutine( card ) );
}
```

Here is the crash log from XCode:

```
2020-08-24 20:45:04.589031+0800 MYAPP[3226:2915180] Task <E65D3D4B-4A00-425C-8316-6C71D2DAFD9F>.<1> HTTP load failed, 564/1774 bytes (error code: -1005 [4:-4])
2020-08-24 20:45:04.589381+0800 MYAPP[3226:2915180] Task <E65D3D4B-4A00-425C-8316-6C71D2DAFD9F>.<1> HTTP load failed, 564/1774 bytes (error code: -1005 [4:-4])
2020-08-24 20:45:04.591199+0800 MYAPP[3226:2915221] Task <E65D3D4B-4A00-425C-8316-6C71D2DAFD9F>.<1> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSUnderlyingError=0x281ca8de0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x2830ec960 [0x1c82af728]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb1288d6140000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask <E65D3D4B-4A00-425C-8316-6C71D2DAFD9F>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalUploadTask <E65D3D4B-4A00-425C-8316-6C71D2DAFD9F>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.trello.com/1/cards/?key="KEY"&token="TOKEN", NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.trello.com/1/cards/?key="KEY"&token="TOKEN", _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
Uploading Crash Report
TrelloException: Could not upload new card to Trello: Cannot connect to destination host
  at Trello.CheckWwwStatus (System.String errorMessage, UnityEngine.WWW www) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at Trello+<UploadCardCO>d__27.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
 
Uploading Crash Report
TrelloException: Could not upload new card to Trello: Cannot connect to destination host
  at Trello.CheckWwwStatus (System.String errorMessage, UnityEngine.WWW www) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at Trello+<UploadCardCO>d__27.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
UnityEngine.UnhandledExceptionHandler:PrintException(String, Exception)
UnityEngine.UnhandledExceptionHandler:HandleUnhandledException(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
System.UnhandledExceptionEventHandler:Invoke(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash was fixed by refactoring the code. Previously I did not know about throwing exception on iOS will cause crashing issue. However I still have the same UnityWebRequest.error return "cannot connect to destination host" on iOS13.5.1 issue. I had open a new thread focusing on this area. Here is the link:
[Unity3D UnityWebRequest.error return "cannot connect to destination host" on iOS13.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610664/unity3d-unitywebrequest-error-return-cannot-connect-to-destination-host-on-ios)